# use wildcard in cache area in appcache

Tags: html, caching, manifest, cdn, html5-appcache

I want to use the appcache for offline viewing of my app and I want to use it as

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
http://cdn.example.com/s/*

NETWORK:
*
```

is there any way the browser will cache all the files in the the 's' folder and if not, is there any way I can specify all the files of particular folder or link to be included in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you [can't use wildcards in the CACHE section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache#Structure_of_a_cache_manifest_file).

The example above will simply attempt to download the file named `*` in the folder `s/` on `cdn.example.com` on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Depends whether you want to explicitly cache all pages in that folder, or simply cache them on a lazy-loading basis (i.e. if a user happens to navigate to one of the pages, it will then be cached for future use).

If you want to cache all the pages up-front, then you need to list them all in the application cache manifest -- I don't believe a wildcard will work.

If you're happy for a page to be cached only once a user has visited it, then you don't need to list the page in the manifest, you simply need to link to the manifest in the relevant page, and it will be cached when it's visited.

You can read more here: http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html